# How to align data in log file using DEBUG in QT?

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, alignment, display

I want to display data in a log file in my QT app. To do so, I use `DEBUG()`.

The data I display is :

```
Time since beginning of the test (ms) :  751  Pressure :  "0.051547" 
Time since beginning of the test (ms) :  2498  Pressure :  "0.116169" 
Time since beginning of the test (ms) :  8498  Pressure :  "0.253792" 
Time since beginning of the test (ms) :  10497  Pressure :  "0.290243" 
Time since beginning of the test (ms) :  12597  Pressure :  "0.316798"
```

But I would like to align the variables as if they were columns.
I want something like this :

```
Time since beginning of the test (ms) :    751  Pressure :  "0.051547" 
Time since beginning of the test (ms) :   2498  Pressure :  "0.116169" 
Time since beginning of the test (ms) :   8498  Pressure :  "0.253792" 
Time since beginning of the test (ms) :  10497  Pressure :  "0.290243" 
Time since beginning of the test (ms) :  12597  Pressure :  "0.316798"
```

The code I am using is :

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < _pressureValues.length() ; i++)
{
    DEBUG() << "Time since beginning of the test (ms) : " << _pressureValues[i].first
            << " Pressure : " << _pressureValues[i].second;
}
```

Is there a function that can specify to display a variable on a certain number of digits ?

Comment: What is `DEBUG()`?

Comment: Yeah right, forgot to say that. 

It is the same as ``qDebug()`` but it writes in my log file in addition to the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that directly with DEBUG() - you need to format the output string beforehand.
[QString](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html) has e.g. the `QString QString::arg(double a, int fieldWidth = 0, char format = 'g', int precision = -1, QChar fillChar = QLatin1Char(' '))` function which allows you to format numbers.

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < _pressureValues.length() ; i++)
{
    const QString firstPressureValue = QString("%1").arg(_pressureValues[i].first, 5);
    DEBUG() << "Time since beginning of the test (ms) : " << firstPressureValue 
        << " Pressure : " << _pressureValues[i].second;
}
```

Though it might be sensible to wrap entire thing in a QString first anyway:

```
QString debugString = QString("Time since beginning of the test (ms) : %1 Pressure : %2");
QString firstPressureValue = QString("%1").arg(_pressureValues[i].first, 5);
DEBUG() << debugString.arg(firstPressureValue, QString::number(_pressureValues[i].second));
```